# Elasticsearch Term suggester not working as expected

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a fields named **title** having the following mapping.

```
{
 "title": {
   "type": "string"
}
```

While doing the term suggester for spellcheck, It is not giving result as expected.

For the query lenovo a1000, it is returning results as below.

```
[spell_suggestion] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => lenovo
                    [offset] => 0
                    [length] => 6
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [text] => a1000
                    [offset] => 7
                    [length] => 5
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [text] => a1018
                                    [score] => 0.6
                                    [freq] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [text] => a102
                                    [score] => 0.5
                                    [freq] => 1
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [text] => a104
                                    [score] => 0.5
                                    [freq] => 1
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [text] => a108
                                    [score] => 0.5
                                    [freq] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But the index has title containing **lenovo a1000**.

I am using the below query for spellcheck.

```
{
    "spell_suggestion": {
        "text": "lenovo a1000",
        "term": {
            "field": "title",
            "sort": "score",
            "prefix_length": 3
        }
    }
}
```

Why is elasticsearch not returning the terms already in index.
Am I doing anything wrong or missing?. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option `suggest_mode` which defaults to:

```
missing: Only provide suggestions for suggest text terms that are not in the index. This is the default.
```

Try to change it as:

```
always: Suggest any matching suggestions based on terms in the suggest text.
```

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-term.html#_common_suggest_options

Comment: I tried that also. But also not giving the text already present in index.